# Can I install a VM inside a VM?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, vmware, metasploit

I am not good at computer. Currently, I'm using Kali Linux as a VM using VMware. I want to install Metasploitable2 using virtual box inside this VM. Can I do that?

Comment: What's your goal? Do you want to use the other VM as an attack target?

Comment: Yes. I just want to use Metasploitable2 inside Kali Linux. But I am using this Kali Linux as a VM. I don't know if I should install another VM inside this VM.

Comment: You are speaking about nested virtualization, which is possible with some hypervisors. https://www.vmwareblog.org/nested-virtualization-vmware-esxi-vs-microsoft-hyper-v/
For your case, you can follow alternative route and install VMware ESXi free on bare metal and use Kali VM with Metasploitable2 on top.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible using Virtualbox. You have to make sure that your vmware version accepts nested virtualization.

Version 5.1 and later:

1
Right-click the virtual machine and select Edit Settings.

a
To locate a virtual machine, select a datacenter, folder, cluster, resource pool, host, or vApp.

b
Click the Related Objects tab and click Virtual Machines.

2
On the Virtual Hardware tab, expand CPU, and select Expose hardware-assisted virtualization to guest OS.

3
Click OK.

The Manage tab refreshes, and the Nested Hypervisor CPU option shows Enabled.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is overcomplicated.

Set up another VM on the host. Configure networking so that both VMs can communicate with each other.

I'm not familiar with VMWare, but in VirtualBox you'd create a new NAT Network (VirtualBox network settings) and connect both VMs to it (VM settings).

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your help.